# Why do unwanted contacts appear on my iPhone when I use gmail app?

Tags: ios, contacts, gmail

I started receiving unwanted contacts being added to my iPhone running iOS 17.3.1 and using the native gmail app.

All I see is a new name and a Gmail address of people I don't even know. I don't know how they are getting there, but they all seem to be from Gmail.

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

That is user setting in Gmail

- When I send a message to a new person, add them to Other Contacts so that I can auto-complete to them next time*

disable that in Gmail settings!!

[image: contacts]